# Cross thread exception Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

This is the code, i want my form keep be alive while downloading code from internet and when its finish i want to update html container. When i do this form freeze. I am new to threading and tasking and i need little help. Thanks!

```
 private void buttonGetHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() => Download(textBoxUrl.Text)).ContinueWith((Download) => htmlContent.Text = Download.Result);
    }

    private string Download(string url)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string context = client.DownloadString(url);
            return context;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ContinueWith` is old style. Async/await is much easier to read, write and understand. It's just a wrapper, why not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
private async void buttonGetHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string context = await client.DownloadStringAsync(textBoxUrl.Text);
        htmlContent.Text = content
    }
}
```

Most people try to solve this with Control.Invoke or something (see link in comment) but in this case there is a better option. Using the Async methods of the `WebClient` class. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync(v=vs.110).aspx

Always look for Async methods first, before starting your own thread instead.

If you cannot use async await try this:

```
private void buttonGetHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = textBoxUrl.Text;
    Task.Run(() => Download(url)).ContinueWith((Download) => { htmlContent.Text = Download.Result; },  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private string Download(string url)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        string context = client.DownloadString(url);
        return context;
    }
}
```

So the call that accesses the UI is out of the Task and the continuation that accesses the UI will run on the UI thread.

Comment: Yes this works but i have to do it without await and async and i have problems...

Comment: Just to be clear, why can't you use async/await?

Comment: I get this error http://i68.tinypic.com/rvlxk0.jpg i can't use async/await becouse this is task from university without async/await

Comment: @ИванЖелев sorry, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext should be TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() updated my answer

Comment: Thanks alot this works !

Answer (score 2):

The reason is calling `textBoxUrl.Text` from non-UI thread. Try to retrieve the text first, then call `Task.Run`:

```
private void buttonGetHTML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = textBoxUrl.Text;
    Task.Run(() => Download(url)).ContinueWith((Download) => htmlContent.Text = Download.Result);
}
```